# Docker build seems to hang when installing non-pip Python packages

Tags: python, docker

I've got some non-pip packages,

which I've written into my requirements.txt as:

```
git+https://github.com/manahl/arctic.git
```

This seems to work OK on my localhost, but when I do docker build I get this:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/manahl/arctic.git (from -r scripts/requirements.txt (line 11))
│  Cloning https://github.com/manahl/arctic.git to /tmp/pip-1gw7spz2-build
```

And it just seems to hang. It moves on silently after several minutes, but it doesn't look like it's worked at all. It seems to do this for every git based dependency.

What am I doing wrong?

Dockerfile:

```
 FROM python:3.6.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

 # Set the working directory to /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

 # Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 ADD . /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
     git\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     build-essential                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

 # Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 RUN pip install -r scripts/requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

 # Run app.py when the container launches                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 CMD ["python", "scheduler.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `scripts` folder exists in current directory try `RUN pip install -r /scripts/requirements.txt`

Comment: That didn't work, in that case it just can't find requirements.txt. Why did you think it would work? (that might help me figure it out)

Comment: I copied requirements.txt to app folder and it worked smoothly.

Comment: Remove the pip installation line and build your container and try to execute the pip installation step manually.